# If there is comparison between two variables then language is not regular. Then how the below two languages L1 and L2 Regular? Please Explain

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

[image]

How these two languages be regular.If there is comparison between m and n since (n < m) is the condition to be satisfied.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! We discourage posts that simply state a problem out of context, and expect the community to solve it. Assuming you tried to solve it yourself and got stuck, it may be helpful if you wrote your thoughts and what you could not figure out. It will definitely draw more answers to your post. Until then, the question will be voted to be closed / downvoted. You may also want to check out [these hints](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98), or use the search engine of this site to find similar questions that were already answered.

Comment: This is not duplicate question i didn't find this question any where earlier. If there is question with explaination please provide the link.

Comment: @ArunKumarSingh, hint, both $L_1$ and $L_2$ are $\{a^t\mid t\ge 1\}$.

Comment: @Apass.Jack we know that even { a^p | p is prime } is not regular language although it is also in the form {a^t | t>= 1} as we can not determine wether p is prime or not so similar condition is also here we can not differentiate in powers of "a" wether "m" is greater than "n" or not.

Comment: @ArunKumarSingh I am not saying $L_1$ is a subset of $\{a^t\mid t\ge1\}$. $L_1$ is **the same as** $\{a^t\mid t\ge1\}$. That is probably what tricked you. $L_2$ **is** $\{a^t\mid t\ge2\}$ (I was wrong saying "... and $L_2$ are $\{a^t\mid t\ge1\}$).

Comment: I just recommended reopening this question since it is NOT covered by answers to the referenced questions. The crux of the question is to understand the usage of free variables.

Comment: @Apass.Jack , Arun Kumar Singh, it should be obvious, without guessing that it is not duplicate, maybe edit would shed some light, give context and state crux of the problem in the body, not comment?